# Using javascript to show a feature layer in arcmap api 3.22 and the feature layer isn't showing up

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

It may be because of how the server is setup? I don't really know and I'm lost. I can only access the data on the ArcGIS server while on the network the server is on, so that may be the issue. 
I'm brand new to using Javascript and ArcGIS server so I'm learning as I go and there really has not been a lot online to self teach this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<title>FeatureLayer</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.22/esri/css/esri.css">
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.22/"></script>

<style>
html, body, #map {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>

<script>
require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(
    Map,
    FeatureLayer
  ) {

    var map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "hybrid",
      center: [ -74.026879,40.168342],
      zoom: 17
    });

    /****************************************************************
     * Add feature layer - A FeatureLayer at minimum should point
     * to a URL to a feature service or point to a feature collection 
     * object.
     ***************************************************************/

    // Carbon storage of trees in Warren Wilson College.
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://wlb-gis-01.monmouth.edu:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Lake_Como/Lake_Como_test/MapServer/0");

    map.addLayer(featureLayer);

  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: layer in not accessible from outside - how can we check the issue if layer itself is not accessible - http://wlb-gis-01.monmouth.edu/arcgis/rest/services/Lake_Como/Lake_Como_test/MapServer/0

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the URL is not public, must be accessible from the local network.
You can ask the network admin if the server can be accessible from internet.